# Write an SQL query to calculate the conversion rate of users from each stage of the sales funnel

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, sum

Consider that, I have a table "Sales" with columns "user_id," "product_id," "timestamp," and "purchase_status." How to Write an SQL query to calculate the conversion rate of users from each stage of the sales funnel (e.g., viewed the product, added to cart, completed the purchase).

Example:

| user_id | product_id | timestamp | purchase_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2023-07-25 08:15:00 | viewed |
| 2 | B | 2023-07-25 09:30:00 | added_to_cart |
| 1 | A | 2023-07-25 10:00:00 | completed |
| 3 | C | 2023-07-25 12:45:00 | viewed |
| 2 | B | 2023-07-25 14:20:00 | completed |

Desired Result:

| purchase_status | viewed_users | added_to_cart_users | completed_users | total_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| viewed | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| Added_to_cart | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| completed | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 |

I have tried writing query like below:

```
SELECT
    purchase_status,
    SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_status = 'viewed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS viewed_users,
    SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_status = 'added_to_cart' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS added_to_cart_users,
    SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_status = 'completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS completed_users,
    COUNT(*) AS total_users
FROM Sales
GROUP BY purchase_status
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN purchase_status = 'viewed' THEN 1
        WHEN purchase_status = 'added_to_cart' THEN 2
        WHEN purchase_status = 'completed' THEN 3
    END;
```

But it is giving result like below that is wrong:

| purchase_status | viewed_users | added_to_cart_users | completed_users | total_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| viewed | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| added_to_cart | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| completed | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 |

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Have you left anything out? Your query seems clean and should return 1 for completed...

Comment: Can a user have more than one row with the same state, and if so what should the result look like?

Comment: @MatBailie - purchase_status is the grouping so the query above should account for all users.

Comment: @RossBush My comment is not directed at you or related to your comment.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the logic of your desired results and I believe that last line should be: |completed|1|1|2|4| as "user_id" 2 has "added_to_cart" "product_id" B, and later "completed" the purchase

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat naive approach would be to pivot the data "per user" first, and then aggregate.

This counts events rather than users. Which means that a user who views the same product twice (or even purchases the same product twice, months apart) may skew the results. It just depends on what you want.

```
WITH
  user_summary AS
(
  SELECT
    user_id,
    product_id,
    purchase_status,
    SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_status = 'viewed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, product_id)
        AS viewed_users,
    SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_status = 'added_to_cart' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, product_id)
        AS added_to_cart_users,
    SUM(CASE WHEN purchase_status = 'completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, product_id)
        AS completed users,
    COUNT(*)
      OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, product_id)
        AS total_users
  FROM
    Sales
)
SELECT
  purchase_status,
  SUM(viewed_users),
  SUM(added_to_cart_users),
  SUM(completed_users),
  SUM(total_users)
FROM
  user_summary
GROUP BY
  purchase_status
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN purchase_status = 'viewed' THEN 1
        WHEN purchase_status = 'added_to_cart' THEN 2
        WHEN purchase_status = 'completed' THEN 3
    END;
```